# Symfony DomCrawler and OpenSSL Connection Reset errors

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, openssl, domcrawler

I am learning Symfony Crawler and want to implement the following scenario:

1. navigate to a certain page
2. fill out a form with data
3. submit the form
4. if you are redirected to example.org/error after submitting, try submitting the form again with different data, and if to another page, download its content.

My code is quite simple (it runs as Symfony Command):

```
    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

    $url = "https://example.org";
    $browser = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create());
    $crawler = $browser->request('GET', $url);
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('submitForm')->form();

    $form['field1'] = 'foo'; //temporary data
    $form['field2'] = 'bar';
    $form['field3'] = 'baz';
    $form['field4'] = '12345';
    $crawler = $browser->submit($form);
    if(!$crawler->getBaseHref() === "https://example.org/error")
    {
        $nodeValues = $crawler->filter('.section')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
            return $node->text();
        });

        $io->info("Important message: ".$nodeValues[0]);

    }
```

After running it, 95% of the time I get the following error message in commandline:

> In ErrorChunk.php line 62:  OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054 for "https://example.org".

> In CurlResponse.php line 337:  OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054 for "https://example.org".

On the other hand, in the remaining 5% of cases I get correct data.
Is this some kind of protection against using the crawler? Or do I need to set something else?

Comment: Looks like your OpenSSL is too old and doesn't support recent TLS versions.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an old version of OpenSSL. Try downloading a new package or compiling from source. Most servers require TLS1.2+ because it is the current standard.